# Highcharts Navigator shows datetime in milliseconds

Tags: highcharts

How can I show datetime in the highcharts navigator as '%b, %Y' instead of milliseconds

SQL Code :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a1.date_time, '%d %b, %Y') AS dt_mon_yr, 
(a4.ph1_active_energy)*10 - a1.ph1_active_energy AS 'ph1', 
(a4.ph2_active_energy)*10 - a1.ph2_active_energy AS 'ph2', 
(a4.ph3_active_energy)*10 - a1.ph3_active_energy AS 'ph3' 
FROM powerpro a1 

JOIN (SELECT DATE(date_time) date, MIN(date_time) AS min 
    FROM powerpro GROUP BY DATE(date_time) 
    ) a2 ON a1.date_time = a2.min 
JOIN (SELECT DATE(date_time) date, MIN(date_time) AS min 
    FROM powerpro GROUP BY DATE(date_time) 
    ) a3 ON DATE(a1.date_time) = a3.date - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
JOIN powerpro a4 
    ON a4.date_time = a3.min 

WHERE DATE(a1.date_time) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW() ORDER BY a1.date_time
```

Comment: It should show time in human readable format (not necessarily '%b, %Y') instead of milliseconds. What does your chart code look like? Did you set the `xAxis.type` to be `'datetime'`?

Comment: Yes. the xAxis.type is already in datetime and ticked as 'mmm, yyyy' format. I think the navigator may automatically get that format. But It had get in milliseconds. What may be going wrong

Comment: Would need to see a representative code example to determine that.

Comment: Added the SQL Code above

Comment: We need to see the highcharts code and that SQL code snippet is not useful as we do not know the data used or what format it is in or what format you are using it as in the highcharts code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use axis labels [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter) and then use [Highcharts.dateFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat)